# Setup PoS private network

Tags: network, casper, private

I need to setup PoS private network with Casper and I cant find any official manual how to do it.
There are only couple links which uses this git repo:
https://github.com/karlfloersch/docker-pyeth-dev

which contains already configured docker files with necessary files.
I would like to know how to do the same, but seems there still no info.

Please advice.

Comment: any particular reason for POS over  classic bft? Have you checked out Fabric or Quorum?

Answer (score 2):

This is absolutely true so far. There is no info about how to setup PoS Casper private network.

But here are some useful links:

- [Installing Casper on Ubuntu](https://github.com/tpmccallum/ethereum_casper_testnet_ubuntu_installation)
- [Casper Pyethapp Development Environment Containers](https://github.com/karlfloersch/docker-pyeth-dev)
- [Casper repository](https://github.com/ethereum/casper)

By the way if you need to setup a PoS private network for work, Casper might not be the best option, because the implementation of this protocol is still at the first stage. There are other PoS blockchains that can suite your needs like Neo, NAV Coin, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I saw all of these 3 links - first two uses Casper Pyethapp Development Environment Containers. Ans seems 3rd link also.